# CSS rotate element while staying inside container

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, transform

If you take a a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/KA4dz/

In this demo, you can clearly see the inner element reaching outside of the outer element due to its rotation. The request is to scale down the inner element (while maintaining aspect ratio's and center positioning) just so it fits within its container.

The use-case is that the user can manually rotate such an inner element while ensuring that it stays within the outer element. (so simply scaling down until it fits for the eyes is not a solution).

This is a scenario where my math skills are clearly lacking. Posting what I've tried wont do much good at this stage. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

One additional requirement is that the inner element only scales down whenever its required but never scales down when its not required (where required means leaving the boundaries of the outer element)

To save a click:

```
.outer{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 100px;
}

.inner{
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;

    transform: rotate(-40deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-40deg);
}

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, if you want to preemptively scale down so it will never leave the container than you need the ratio of the hypotenuse to the shorter side.  50 / sqrt(100^2 + 50^2)

Comment: Is the inner block supposed to change sizes as a user rotates the item?

Comment: Also, please include your JS for rotating the item ;)

Comment: @gvee yes thats correct. there is no JS in the demo and i dont think we need it because the JS is simply applying a rotate transform using https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable as a basis

Comment: @MikeEdwards That would be correct given the question however not with my actual request (and i'll update the question accordingly) for preemptively scaling down is only required when the inner element is leaves the boundaries of the outer element. Else no scaling is desired. Your suggestion would scale down the element if not perfectly square shaped even if its not exceeding its container

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/KA4dz/18/

Comment: @JasonNichols Yep that's the behavior I'm looking for. Just need to derive how to do the scaling calculation.

Comment: So, it is to scale while it rotates, if it is determined that the rotation would leave it outside the bounds of the outer box?

Comment: I've come up with this so far in JS. I know it's not 100% there yet (more like 50% to be honest) but should give you a start. Can't spend any more time just now.  http://jsfiddle.net/KA4dz/20/

Comment: @gvee Thanks! I'll play around with it a bit. see what we can make out of it!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was interesting. Here's my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/fletiv/jrHTe/

And javascript looks like this:

```
(function () {

var setRotator = (function () {

    var setRotation,
        setScale,
        offsetAngle,
        originalHeight,
        originalFactor;

    setRotation = function (degrees, scale, element) {
        element.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg) scale(' + scale + ')';
        element.style.transform = 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg) scale(' + scale + ')';
    };

    getScale = function (degrees) {

        var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180,
            sum;

        if (degrees < 90) {
            sum = radians - offsetAngle;
        } else if (degrees < 180) {
            sum = radians + offsetAngle;
        } else if (degrees < 270) {
            sum = radians - offsetAngle;
        } else {
            sum = radians + offsetAngle;
        }

        return (originalHeight / Math.cos(sum)) / originalFactor;
    };

    return function (inner) {

        offsetAngle = Math.atan(inner.offsetWidth / inner.offsetHeight);
        originalHeight = inner.offsetHeight;
        originalFactor = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(inner.offsetHeight, 2) + Math.pow(inner.offsetWidth, 2));

        return {

            rotate: function (degrees) {
                setRotation (degrees, getScale(degrees), inner);
            }
        }
    };

}());

var outer = document.getElementById('outer'),
    inner = document.getElementById('inner'),
    rotator = setRotator(inner),
    degrees = 0;

window.setInterval(function () {
    degrees += 1;

    if (degrees >= 360) {
        degrees = 0;
    }

    rotator.rotate(degrees);
}, 50);

}());
```

Edit: Here's an image which tries to explain the logic of my code. :)

[image]

Comment: You've seem to have nailed it good sir! I will be glad to accept this answer. Would you mind explaining your solution a bit? Although its pretty easy to derive from the code posted, it would help me and future readers in understanding the logic!

Comment: Sure! Added an image to explain, because I'm awful at explaining with words. :)

Comment: your image did the job just fine!

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version of Matti's answer

```
var scaler = function (id, degrees) {
        var inner = document.getElementById(id);
        offsetAngle = Math.atan(inner.offsetWidth / inner.offsetHeight);
        originalHeight = inner.offsetHeight;
        originalFactor = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(inner.offsetHeight, 2) + Math.pow(inner.offsetWidth, 2));
        var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180,
            sum, result;
        if (degrees < 90) {
            sum = radians - offsetAngle;
        } else if (degrees < 180) {
            sum = radians + offsetAngle;
        } else if (degrees < 270) {
            sum = radians - offsetAngle;
        } else {
            sum = radians + offsetAngle;
        }
        var result = (originalHeight / Math.cos(sum)) / originalFactor;
        inner.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(' + result+ ')';
        inner.style.transform = 'scale(' + result+ ')';
}
```