# Scaling a rotated rectangle to the minimum size needed to cover it's container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math, trigonometry

I have a rectangle frame, as well as a second rectangle which can rotate. I would like the determine what minimum scale needs to be applied to the rotating rectangle in order to completely cover the stationary frame.

[image]

I have seen solutions to similar problems which solve for the maximum scale to *contain* the rotating rect within the parent, but I'm not able to decipher how they function in order to figure out what changes would be necessary to modify them for my use case of covering it.

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794171/css-rotate-element-while-staying-inside-container) shows how to contain the rotating rect, in which the scale to apply is calculated as the current distance from corner to corner over the original distance from corner to corner. Inverting that DOES actually achieve what I'm looking for, but only works if both the child and the parent are the same size. You can see in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/GtwoK/pen/vYMmJoY) how it functions, but if you change the aspect-ratio of `#rect1`, it no longer works.

[This 2nd example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66917314/how-to-rescale-a-continuously-rotating-element-to-fit-exactly-in-its-fixed-size) works with 2 rectangles of any size (here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/GtwoK/pen/rNbmGbE) link), however, I can't decipher how it functions enough to cause the rectangle to cover the frame, rather than be contained to within it.

Would anyone be able to help calculate what is necessary to achieve this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I don't think the problem is fully defined. Is the pink 'rectangle' always to be a square as shown in the first diagram? Or can it have any random aspect ratio?

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wvxj39eh/) what you are looking for? If not, please let me know what have I got wrong.

Comment: @kikon yes! That's absolutely exactly what I'm looking for, thank you so much. If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code base from the codepens you linked to, and using simple trigonometry, the diagonal of the inner rectangle that touches the outer rectangle of minimum size, can be used to determine one of that rectangles's sides and from that its scale to the original version. Better seen in code than in words:

```js
const cont= document.querySelector('#rect2');
const rot= document.querySelector('#rect1');
const hRot = rot.offsetHeight, h = cont.offsetHeight;
const wRot = rot.offsetWidth, w = cont.offsetWidth;

let t=0; 
const anim= setInterval(rotate, 10);
function rotate(){
    rot.style.transform = "rotate(-" + t + "deg)";
    update(t);
    t += 0.1;
    t = t % 360;
}

function update(T){
  T = T % 180; 
  T = T > 90 ? 180 - T : T;
  const phi = degToRad(T),
     sin_phi = Math.sin(phi),
     cos_phi = Math.cos(phi),
     ratio1 = (w * cos_phi + h * sin_phi) / wRot,
     ratio2 = (w * sin_phi + h * cos_phi) / hRot,
     ratio = Math.max(ratio1, ratio2);
  
  rot.style.transform += " scale(" + ratio + ")";
}

function degToRad(angle){
 return angle * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
#rect1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
/*   transform: rotate(50deg); */
}
#rect2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="rect1"></div>
<div id="rect2"></div>
```

The same in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvxj39eh/) from the original message; it allows one to play with the sizes and aspect-ratios of the two rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, the width of the rotating square should be the hypotenuse of the reference square. Then to get the scale, just divide by the width of the rotating square.

Not sure in if you need this in javascript like the examples? You can handle the majority of this with just css. The only thing you need javascript for is to dynamically update the scale css variable, since css doesn't support this, yet...

```js
let rect = {
      ref: document.querySelector('.rect.ref'),
      rot: document.querySelector('.rect.rot'),
      get_scale: () =>
        Math.hypot(rect.ref.clientHeight, rect.ref.clientWidth) / rect.rot.clientWidth,
      set_scale: () => {
        document.getElementById('scale').innerHTML =
          `:root { --rotate-scale: ${rect.get_scale()}; }`;
      }
  };

//this is just to make it interactive
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((input, index, inputs) => {
  input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    rect.ref.style.aspectRatio = ([...inputs].map((i) => i.value).join(' / '));
    rect.set_scale();
  });
});
```

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) scale(var(--rotate-scale)) }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) scale(var(--rotate-scale)) }
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center; }
  
.aspect {
  display: grid;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1; }

.rect {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px; }

.rect.ref {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1; }

.rect.rot {
  animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: #ff000050;
  border-color: #ff000050; }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style id="scale">
      <!-- start with the hypotenuse of the unit square, aka sqrt(2) -->
      :root { --rotate-scale: 1.412; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="aspect">
      <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1">
      <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1">
    </div>
    
    <div class="rect ref"></div>
    <div class="rect rot"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```